# Replacing an extension-less image in gmail HTML view with tampermonkey

Tags: tampermonkey

On HTML gmail view top left corner the new Gmail logo could be seen. I want to replace it with the old one ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXzmx.png ) but I'm not sure how. I've tried a 9 year old stackoverflow thread but it didn't work since the gmail logo link isn't a link to the file with an extension.

Answer (score 0):

found a way

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Image Replacer
// @version      1.1
// @description  Image Replacer
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
// @match        https://www.pinterest.com/pin/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

/*globals $*/

var old_url = "https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/WQ_JO_iFWK3AKuIPeHz_fnMMOaGLG0HAsCJWOkWiRo9Oa_NHUeQYCdmJEfw8llIVJ8fMP1mriJ81iPzrebHtesFsF7VIDS0QKCFmqu_RMT_-ow=s0-d-e1-ft"
var new_url = "https://i.imgur.com/kAQfeoj.png"
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img[src='"+old_url+"']").attr("src", new_url);
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).